# delete only the unnecessary 0s from the beginning of the number

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a js string representing a number. I want remove only unnecessary 0s from the beginning of the string and put a 0 before comma if no digit exists, with regex:

```
var regex = ?
var replace = ?

new = "0001,3".replace(regex, replace); // 1,3
new = ",3".replace(regex, replace); // 0,3
new = "000,34".replace(regex, replace); // 0,34
new = "0201,3".replace(regex, replace); // 201,3
new = "0002,03".replace(regex, replace); // 2,03
```

I've tried:

```
new = string.replace(/^0+(,)/g, '$1').replace(/^,/g), '0,');
```

But looks like second replace doesn't work.

Comment: `",3".replace(regex, replace); // 0,3` are you sure you want *replacement* or just parsing this string into a number?

Comment: Use `parseFloat` instead of using regex, `parseFloat('0001.3')`

Comment: @Ammar won't work with a comma as decimal separator.

Comment: @Ammar `parseFloat('0001,3'.replace(',','.'))` since OP isn't using dots and parse doesn't work with commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function trimZeroesLeft(txt) {
  return ("0" + txt).replace(/^0+(?=\d)/g, "");
}

function trimZeroesRight(txt) {
  return txt.replace(/,0*$|(,\d+?)0+$/g, "$1");
}

function trimZeroes(txt) {
  return ("0"+txt).replace(/^0+(?=\d)|,0*$|(,\d+?)0+$/g, "$1");
}


let arr = ["0001,3", ",300", "000,34", "0201,30", "0002,03", "012,0", "0,00"];

console.log("trimZeroesLeft", arr.map(v => `${v} -> ${trimZeroesLeft(v)}`));
console.log("trimZeroesRight", arr.map(v => `${v} -> ${trimZeroesRight(v)}`));
console.log("trimZeroes", arr.map(v => `${v} -> ${trimZeroes(v)}`));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

Comment: Does it work for ",3" without putting "0", in front, before regex replacement ?

Comment: No. That's exactly what this `"0"+` is there for.

Comment: I understand now.

Comment: Your regex doesn't work for ",3" situation. This is my code:
    return ('0' + a.replace(/\D/g, '')).replace(/^0+(?=\d)/g, '');

Comment: `a.replace(/\D/g, '')` will delete everything that is not a number; including the `,`

Answer (score 3):

### Using Regex to replace the `0`s.

```js
function trim(txt) {
  return txt.replace(/^(0*)(,?)/, (full, zeros, end) => end ? "0," : "");
  // If the zeros are directly followed by a `,` then keep a `0`
  // use `function (){return arguments[2] ? "0," : "";}` for ES5
}

console.log(trim("0001,3"));
console.log(trim(",3"));
console.log(trim("000,34"));
console.log(trim("0201,3"));
console.log(trim("0002,03"));
```

### Using parsing and stringify (will replace `0` at the start and the end)

```js
function trim(txt) {
  return String(+(txt.replace(",", "."))).replace(".", ",");
}

console.log(trim("0001,3"));
console.log(trim(",3"));
console.log(trim("000,34"));
console.log(trim("0201,3"));
console.log(trim("0002,03"));
```

Comment: You forgot ",3" in regex solution. Should be converted in "0,3".

Comment: I don't understand your replace regex.

Comment: @ValentinTanasescu `^(0*)` will get any `0`s at the start of the string.  `(,?)` will check if the `0`s are followed by a `,` and will keep a zero in that case.

Comment: I don't understand this "(full, zeros, end) => end"

Comment: The params that are passed to a replace function are `fullMatch, $1, $2, $3...$n`. So `full` is the full match of the regex. `zeros` is `$1` and `end` is `$2`. So `(full, zeros, end) => end ? "0," : ""` is pretty much `if $2 then "0," else ""`. Can also be written as `function (){return arguments[2] ? "0," : "";}` if you think that is easier to read.